# NHibernate throws TypeLoadException under mono

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, mono

I have a .Net based command line app that interacts (CRUD) with PostgreSQL 9.1. Using Nuget, the project currently references NHibernate 3.2.0.4000 and FluentHibenrate 1.3.0.717

Now the code runs fine under .Net environment (meaning Windows Xp/7), but under Mono (Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)), I am seeing TypeLoadException within NHibernate from the exact same code (I did not re-compile anything for mono.). Can someone help and point the way? Thanks!

Here is the stack trace

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

 ---> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

 ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: (XmlDocument) ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect+NoOpViolatedConstraintNameExtracter' from assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.2.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4'.
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping (NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema.HbmMapping mappingDocument, System.String documentFileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow (System.Exception exception) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping (NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema.HbmMapping mappingDocument, System.String documentFileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument (NHibernate.Cfg.NamedXmlDocument doc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocumentThroughQueue (NHibernate.Cfg.NamedXmlDocument document) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader (System.Xml.XmlReader hbmReader, System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream (System.IO.Stream xmlInputStream, System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 


  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProj.Repository.FluentNHibernateHelperPostgreSQL.CreateSessionFactory () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProj.Repository.FluentNHibernateHelperPostgreSQL.get_SessionFactory () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProj.Repository.FluentNHibernateHelperPostgreSQL.OpenSession () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProj.Repository.NHibernateSessionHelper.SmartSessionFactory () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProj.Repository.NHibernateSessionHelper.DoAnything (MyProj.Repository.TargetMethod target) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyProj.Program+<>c__DisplayClass10.<RetrieveDataDriver>b__a () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is the relevant code for FluentNHibernateHelperPostgreSQL.CreateSessionFactory ()

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
  {
      FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure();
      PostgreSQLConfiguration standard = PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard;
      FluentConfiguration fluentConfiguration1 = fluentConfiguration.Database(((PersistenceConfiguration<PostgreSQLConfiguration, PostgreSQLConnectionStringBuilder>)standard).ConnectionString((PostgreSQLConnectionStringBuilder c) => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionStringKey")));
      ISessionFactory sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration1.Mappings((MappingConfiguration m) => m.AutoMappings.Add(FluentNHibernateHelperPostgreSQL.CreateAutomappings)).ExposeConfiguration(FluentNHibernateHelperPostgreSQL.BuildSchema).BuildSessionFactory();
      return sessionFactory;
  }
```

Comment: It looks like one of your mapping documents references a type that Mono can't find.  If you have log4net configuret in nHibernate you should be able to see more details about what document and what type it is trying to load. To do this add log4net appenders to your config file like described here http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx and then remember to call log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator() before trying to create the sessionfactory

Comment: I was able to get log4net to generate logs. However, it does not yet pinpoint exact cause. In either cases, log4net shows that the code was able to generate <hibernate-mapping> xml blob. The only difference is that Windows outputs `2012-09-18 01:18:27,508 [1] INFO  NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` whereas, mono outputs `2012-09-18 01:03:31,529 [1] ERROR NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - Could not compile the mapping document: (XmlDocument)`

I will need to play with log4net some more and see if it can generate any more in-depth log

Comment: I would test with Mono 2.11.4

Comment: You should be able to get a lot more information from log4net about what is going on than "Could not compile the mapping document". It is some DLL that nhibernate can't load it can either be Npsql because of  a version that NHibernate.Driver.Npsql is compiled against and that could be solved with a bindingRedirect, but you need to find out what is actually going on first :-)

Comment: @miracledev, my log4net config is straight out of the nforge link you provided with the change that set `<level value="ALL" />` for `<root>`, `<logger name="NHibernate">`, and `<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">`. Are there additional config I can use to spit out more logs? Or Do I have to somehow open the VS solution under MonoDevelop, set Break point and debug? @knocte, okay, I will look into deploying this on ubuntu Thanks

Comment: Try to add %exception to your ConversionPattern, that way you will get the exception. And in your case, the inner exception that contains all the good details :-)

Comment: @miracledev, I didn't get to work on getting the bottom of the InnerException, but you must be right about missing implementation from Mono in 2.10.8. I took knocte's suggestion and deployed 2.11.3 via https://raw.github.com/nathanb/iws-snippets/master/mono-install-scripts/ubuntu/install_mono-2.11.sh on my ubuntu box, and the code is now working fine. So my bad for not trying out the bleeding edge version before asking the question.

Comment: I spent the past hour trying to process InnerExceptions, but the problem lays with the fact that I am using log to pinpoint the cause, when I should use a debugger to literally debug through and determine the root cause. But then, the code was compiled on VS2010, and I have no experience in debugging the code with Mono, so I will need to learn a few more things before I can figure out what went wrong. In the meantime, I am very happy that the code does work with 2.11.3

Comment: I encountered the same issue with 2.10.8. Strange effect was it worked on my dev machine, but not on the production server. Installing the `mono-devel` package solved it for me. I assume it's any one of the `libmono-*` assemblies missing in the GAC, but they're quite too many for me to manually test which one it was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to manually deploy the latest Mono package from go-mono.com
As suggested by knocte in the comment section, `2.11.4` solved the problem.

I haven't tried 3.x, but so far, I have been happy 2.11.x with no reason to jump into 3.x ship yet.